# Android - How to send an ArrayList without using Intent?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `Activity` and an `Adapter Class`. In my `Adapter` class, I have an `ArrayList` that I want to use in the `Activity` class. And `Recycler view` of `Activity` class is attached to the `adapter` class So, I cannot use `intent` to send it. So, Is there any other way I can access the `ArrayList`?

Comment: Why don't you just add a getter() to adapter and call it from activity?

Comment: @ali73 how to do that?

Comment: please confirm .. do you have one activity with recycle view and you want to access list of recycle view's adapter in a different activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your adapter as follow -

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.CustomViewModel> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> stringList;

    public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> stringList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewModel onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new CustomViewModel(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycle_view_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewModel holder, int position) {
        //put your code of binding of code
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (stringList!= null)
            return stringList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    //getter method of Adpater to return string
    public List<String> getStringList() {
        return stringList;
    }

    public class CustomViewModel extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //your inner class code here
    }
}
```

Now you can get List from your adapter as follows-

```
recycleViewAdapter.getStringList();
```

Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have three ways to do it:

1. move your ArrayList to ViewModel, then pass it to your adapter or use it in the activity.
2. place ArrayList just in the activity and pass it to the adapter.
3. create a getter in your adapter and use it in the activity.